# creating tables with ids with jquery and json

Tags: jquery, json, html

I am trying to build an html-table with jquery. The data I am going to use is coming from a json-file. By now I am using a specific json-file per row. i. e. "adressen1.json", "adressen2.json" and so on.

Is it possible to merge these json-files?

When a row is created a button will be created, too. On click on this button the data of this row is displayed in second place. Unfortunately is does not work for me. Perhaps I am missing something.

Thank you for your support in advance.

Here is the HTML-code:

```
<div id="area_test">
    <table class="testtable_head">
        <tr>
            <th> Button </th>   
            <th> Name </th>
            <th> PLZ </th>
            <th> Ort </th>
            <th> Land </th>
            <th> Referenz </th>
            <th> Gesperrt </th>
        </tr>
        <tbody class="testtable_body">
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <div id="json_2">

    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the jQuery-code and the json-file:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON( "js/adressen1.json", function( data ) {
        $(".testtable_body").append("<tr><td><button id='test_1'>JSON</button></td><td>" + data.Name + "</td>   <td>" + data.postleitzahl + "</td><td>" + data.Ort + "</td><td>" + data.Land + "</td><td>" + data.Referenz +  "</td><td>" + data.Sperre + "</td></tr>");
    }); 

    $( "#test_1" ).click(function() {
    $.getJSON( "js/adressen1.json", function( data ) {
        $("#json_2").append(data.Vorname + " " + data.Name + "<br>" data.postleitzahl + " " + data.Ort);
    });
});

{
    "an": "Herrn",
    "Titel": "Dr.",
    "Vorname": "Klaus",
    "Name": "Meier",
    "Zusatz": "",
    "Strasse": "Goldstraße 56",
    "postleitzahl": "78966",
    "Ort": "Berlin",
    "Land": "DE",
    "Info": "",
    "Kurzname": "KM",
    "Sperre": "Offene Rechnung",
    "Referenz": ""
}
```

Comment: The click event of the button doesn't fire? Is that correct?

Comment: try `$("#testtable_body").on('click', 'button', function() { //your code});`

Comment: Exactly, even a simple "alert('Hello World')" does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can. Simply add all rows to array

```
[
    {"an": "Herrn", "Titel": "Dr."}, 

    {"an": "Herrn", "Titel": "Dr."}
]
```

And use a loop to process data

```
$.getJSON( "js/adressen1.json", function( data ) {
    var html = "";
    data.forEach(function(item, idx){
        html += "<tr><td><button data-id=" + idx+ ">JSON</button></td><td>" + data.Name + "</td>   <td>" + data.postleitzahl + "</td><td>" + data.Ort + "</td><td>" + data.Land + "</td><td>" + data.Referenz +  "</td><td>" + data.Sperre + "</td></tr>"    
    });
    $(".testtable_body")
        .append(html)
        .on('click', 'button[data-id]', function(){
            var item = data[$(this).data('id')];
            $("#json_2").append(item.Vorname + " " + item.Name + "<br>" item.postleitzahl + " " + item.Ort);
    });
});
```